# Category id in forms - model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a 2 models: a *product* and a *category* model with the following association:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, presence: true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :products
end
```

When I try to create a new product using simple_form, in the category_id field, instead of having the id of the category, I want to have the name of the category.

```
<%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :price %>
    <%= f.input :category_id %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would have something like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :price %>
    <%= f.association :category, collection: 
                   Category.all, prompt: "Choose a category"%>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I does work but is it good to have `Category.all` in the views?

Comment: @DaveTheGray I guess you could get away with it, by all means so long as your view does not look like this - http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model That is a very popular blog written there. From first example there is a lot of logic in the view. But many will say to keep your logic to a bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks, just a small typo in your answer on `Category.all`